# Displaying a list of images using AJAX in Codeigniter by querying image filenames form database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a list of filenames of some images stored in a database. I'm trying to get that list using ajax but I am getting the warning message:

`[json] (php_json_encode) type is unsupported, encoded as null`

Below is my code:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Create extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('get_files');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Create New Map';
        $this->load->view('head&foot/create_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('create', $data);
        $this->load->view('head&foot/create_footer');
    }

    // Loads the default tiles into the gallery
    public function update_gallery()
    {
        echo json_encode($this->get_files->get_image_list()); 
    }

}
?>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

/*
 * Returns a list of files from a database
 */

class Get_files extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function get_image_list(){
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_tile");
    }
}

?>
```

**In my view the ajax request is:**

```
$.ajax({
          url:'create/update_gallery',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(data){
            $('#default_tiles_view').html(data);
          }
       })
```

Can any see what is causing the warning?

Comment: What does `$this->get_files->get_image_list()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `get_image_list()` method. It does not actually return an image list, but a [`database result object`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html): the result of `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_tile")`.

In that function you will need to loop through the result set to get all your images in a list (array) and return that list from the function.

Example:

```
function get_image_list(){
    $images = array();
    $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_tile");

    // simple example
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) 
    {
      $images[] = $row;
    }

    return $images;
}
```